# Escape string inside of function scope

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to escape a string passed by parameter inside of the function scope?

I mean instead of:

```
HWND WinExist(std::wstring WinClass, std::wstring WinTitle)
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowEx(0, 0, WinClass.c_str(), WinTitle.c_str());
    if (int err = GetLastError()) GetLastErrorAsString(err, __func__);
    return hWnd;
}

HWND hWnd = WinExist(L"", LR"(a string that need to be escaped)");
```

To something like:

```
HWND WinExist(std::wstring WinClass, std::wstring WinTitle)
{
    // -- escape the string --
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowEx(0, 0, WinClass.c_str(), WinTitle.c_str());
    if (int err = GetLastError()) GetLastErrorAsString(err, __func__);
    return hWnd;
}

HWND hWnd = WinExist(L"", L"a string that need to be escaped");
```

Comment: What's the difference in this instance between the two `WinExist()`s? The first doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Makes no sense. Escape sequences are used when a communication protocol assigns special meaning to certain characters. `FindWindowEx` doesn't.

Comment: Besides, the `GetLastError` call is displaced. It will only return meaningful values under certain conditions. You are failing to evaluate those conditions. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) will tell you. The call also needs to be `FindWindowExW`, not `FindWindowEx`.

Answer (score 1):

No.  At least, not the way you want.

String escape sequences are processed by the compiler while it is processing string *literals*.  They are part of transforming *source code* into a program.  That is, it transforms the string literal `"\n"` into the byte sequence `{0x0A, 0x00}`.  That means it cannot be applied later to a string *variable* at runtime.  It's too late.

Now, you could do a reverse mapping.  i.e. transform the sequence of bytes `{0x0A 0x00}` to `{0x5C, 0x6C, 0x00}`, but I wouldn't call that escaping; it's just applying a transformation.

---

Note that there are other types of escaping that can be applied to string variables (i.e. escaping characters with special meaning in a string that will later be interpreted as a SQL query), but those don't apply here.  Those take one sequence of bytes and transform it into a different sequence of bytes.  They are applied at *runtime*.